# Renaming a primary key in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key

In my android application i have a predefined database which is in the assets folder. In this database there is a table named WMExecutiveActivity. It has 5 primary keys. Now I want to rename one of them. can anyone plz be so kind enough to expalin how do I rename a primary key in sqlite ? Here is my attempt. But it's not working .

```
ALTER TABLE WMExecutiveActivity CHANGE CategoryCode ComplaintActivityCategory char( 4 )
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)) it is not possible to change the table in that way.

> The ALTER TABLE command in SQLite allows the user to rename a table or
>   to add a new column to an existing table. It is not possible to rename
>   a column, remove a column, or add or remove constraints from a table.

Comment: Then what should I do ? I need to rename that column.

Comment: You could add a new column with the new name and leave the "old" column empty. You can then use a trigger (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) to synchronize the two columns with each other so they will contain the same value and are handled as one column.

Comment: @Ann18 Or you can recreate table copying data from former one.